# How to get __proto__ in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance

So when i declare an array as `var arr = []` in browser console and then do `arr.__proto__` i get the prototype in console.

[Browser Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxIH3.png)

But when i do the same thing in nodeJs i get `[]` as result.

[NodeJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n4EC.png)

Nodejs is javascript running on server so why is the result not same . Am i missing something ? How do i access the prototype in nodeJs and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is simply a quirk due to display differences. `arr.__proto__` points to the exact same object in both cases - `Array.prototype` - it's just that your browser and Node present the object to the user for display differently.

You already can access, for example, `arr.__proto__.fill` in Node, even though it's not displayed in the console when logging `arr.__proto__`. You can iterate over the properties manually to display them if you want:

```js
const arr = [];
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr.__proto__).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

The above will show you the exact same results in both environments.

If you hook up Node to [Chrome's console](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27), you'll see that `console.log(arr.__proto__)` looks exactly the same when looking at the log from Node in Chrome, and when looking at the log from a webpage in Chrome.

But, do note that `__proto__` is deprecated - you should prefer to use `Object.getPrototypeOf` nowadays.

Comment: Okay got it ! thanks a lot for clarifying this for me I was banging my head from yesterday over this . Even I thought that i am able to access arr.push and every other function then it should in prototype but not seeing in on console got me confused on this whole concept. Thanks a lot for your answer